# Detect when at least one analog sensor (of many) is active

Tags: analog, sensor

I'm building a digital piano. The current design is one sensor per note to measure position, 8 sensors to a mux, with many muxes. I read muxes/sensors sequentially, and I have logic that uses the position and speed measurements to generate notes. This works fine on a 24 key prototype, but scanning speed would be too slow with more keys. To address this, I want to ignore a mux if all sensors connected to it are reading near 0v. I think I can check that by connecting all sensor outputs to one pin of the mux (with diodes to prevent interference), and read that pin to get a combined measurement of the voltage across all sensors. Then I could could ignore a group of keys if their combined voltage is significantly low. I would need to play around to find the right balance between dead zone and skipping muxes.

Questions:

1. Does that sound like a reasonable approach?
2. If the logic were reversed, and sensors were high when the keys were inactive and low when the keys were depressed, is there also a simple way of aggregating the signal for a joint reading of sensors to see if a group of sensors is inactive?

Comment: What kind of sensor do you use?

Comment: Instead of muxing everything into one MCU input, why don't you do (say) 8x parallel muxing into 8x MCU inputs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Antonio51 linear hall effect sensors.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm aware that on a teensy it is possible to read both adcs simultaneously 
- is that the sort of thing you're referring to? I'm using a pico, which only has a single on board adc that is multiplexed to 3 pins. So even with muxes on each of the three pins I still need to read sequentially.

Comment: @testing67  [Interesting problem.  +1 to the question.]  You wrote that your setup with muxes is fast enough for 24 keys, but not for more keys.  Do you know where the bottleneck is?  Is it on the A/D conversion time, or in the mux switching time?  Or somewhere else?  What type of mux are you currently using?  How quickly do you want to scan the keys which are active?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Even without ADC, my code is still not fast enough. I measure key position then run a physics simulation calculating position and speed of hammer in response to key movement. I'm not sure how much time is spent in ADC relative to that. If there is a straightforward way of essentially reducing the number of keys by skipping inactive groups, then that would give me a lot of leeway with regards to optimization (but I could definitely do more optimization).

Comment: @NickAlexeev I was using the mcp3008 (adc + 8 channel mux), but to reduce cost am switching over to CD74HC4067 (16 channel mux) with the internal pico adc. I want to complete one scanning cycle within 5000us, fastest note press time on a piano is approximately 10000us. 88 keys are essential. More (300-400) would be nice, for experimenting with alternative keyboard layouts that have multiple keys/buttons per note (like the janko keyboard).

Comment: @testing67  I'd like to invite your question to a different electronics Q&A site: https://electrical.codidact.com .  A significant number of heavy lifters from Electonics.StackExchange moved over there.  (I understand your problem, and I can propose a few solutions.  On Codidact that would be.)